# How do JavaScript members/properties work?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between an object create with this syntax: `{ prop1: val1, prop2: val2 }`, and an object created with this syntax: `{ 'prop1': val1, 'prop2': val2 }`?

And also, does the following code work?

```
var val1 = 10, val2 = 15;
var tmp1 = { prop1: val1 };
var tmp2 = { 'prop2': val2 };
alert(tmp1['prop1']); // I expect 10
alert(tmp2['prop2']); // I expect 15
```

---

P.S.: Sorry, I couldn't come up with a better title for my question. That reflects my lack of knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: Suggest using http://jsfiddle.net/ for finding out if JS snippets work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference at all, although the string version lets you use characters that are not valid characters for identifiers.

You can do this with strings:

```
{ 'prop-1': val1, 'prop-2': val2 }
```

But not as identifiers:

```
{ prop-1: val1, prop-2: val2 }
```

And yes, that code works.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference in your examples. You *would* need the quotes if any of your property names had spaces or special characters or were otherwise [not a valid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names/1661249#1661249):

```
{ prop1 with spaces: val1, 6prop2$-^: val2 } // illegal 
{ 'prop1 with spaces': val1, '6prop2$-^': val2 } // correct
```